# Sections with poles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective complex curve, and let $A_X=H^0(X-p,\mathcal O_X)$, where $p$ is a fixed point of $X$.

> is it true that $A_X=\bigcup_{n\geq0 }H^0(X,\mathcal O_X(np))$?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is yes.